# RemoteAction not respecting sharing settings

Tags: apex, visualforce, permissions, remote-action

I have a RemoteAction in my code that queries data. I receive all the records irrespective of the fact that `with sharing` has been used for the containing class.

Does `RemoteAction` NOT respect sharing settings?

I read the documentations [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_vf_remoting_apex_mode.htm) and [here](http://www.ceus-now.com/sharing-without-sharing-and-remoteaction/). and my Controller version is 36.0. but still not pretty sure.

Comment: Are you sure ?With sharing should respect sharing settings ?Check for profile of the user to see he does not have view ALl or modify all access ?

Comment: Yes @MohithShrivastava...on adding the solution by Adrian it seems to work. But not sure why it returns all the records without it. Have raised a ticket with Salesforce...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was only able to reproduce the behavior you describe by changing the controller to `without sharing`. Regardless, this workaround should let you filter out records which should not be viewable:

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<MyObject__c> getRecords()
{
    Map<Id, MyObject__c> records = new Map<Id, MyObject__c>([
        SELECT Name FROM MyObject__c
    ]);

    List<MyObject__c> viewable = new List<MyObject__c>();
    for (UserRecordAccess access : [
        SELECT RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess
        WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
        AND HasReadAccess = true
        AND RecordId IN :records.keySet()
    ]) viewable.add(records.get(access.RecordId));
    return viewable;
}
```

Comment: The fix works. Not sure about the issue with sharing in RemoteAction...Thanks :)